# Spring LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean scanForPackages and Hibernate package-level type definitions

Tags: spring, jpa, hibernate-mapping

In Spring 3.1 and higher the [LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) is supposed to be able to configure the JPA EntityManagerFactory without a persistence.xml.  The configuration is included in the bean definition for  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean instead.

When I use the packagesToScan method to tell the factory bean where to scan for my entity classes it doesn't seem to be picking up my [Hibernate type definitions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e2957) which are defined at the package level.

package-info.java:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs({
    @org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef(name = "TypeA", typeClass = com.foo.type.A.class),
    @org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef(name = "TypeB", typeClass = com.foo.type.B.class) }) package com.foo.type;
```

spring-jpa.xml:

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>       
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>                               
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="com.foo.FooDialect" />
            <entry key="hibernate.default_schema" value="dba"/>             
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
            <entry key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="META-INF/ehcache.xml" />
            <entry key="javax.persistence.validation.factory" value-ref="validator"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan"> 
        <list>
            <value>com.foo.domain</value>
            <value>com.foo.type</value>
        </list>
    </property>             
</bean>
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score -1):

I found that adding a @MappedSuperclass annotation to the package level typedefs causes Hibernate to find and process them.  It doesn't seem like a very pretty solution, so I'm still looking for a better way if one exists.

package-info.java:

```
@MappedSuperclass // <---HACK TO CAUSE HIBERNATE TO NOTICE THESE TYPE DEFS
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "TypeA", typeClass = com.foo.type.A.class),
    @TypeDef(name = "TypeB", typeClass = com.foo.type.B.class) 
}) 
package com.foo.type;

import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
```

Comment: I have faced the same issue. But as you mention when I add the @MappedSuperclass I will get following Maven error -------->           ERROR]  core\model\package-info.java:[2,0] error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration